# What is the cause of an "APPROVED" transaction but doesnt do a "TRANSFER" for an ERC-20 Token?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, erc-20-approve

I have a transaction that was approved and I paid $3 in fees. But the token was never "transfered" where and how can I debug what happen to my transaction of why it didn't transfer?

Comment: It may means the transaction failed but it didn't revert. Some tokens do not fully implement ERC20 standard and they may not revert in case of an error.

Comment: You gave the approval to the "third party", now you need to trigger the transaction